# Pandas dataframe groupby make a list or array of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {'a': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaa'], 
      'b':['bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bbb', 'bbb'], 
      'c':[10,20,30,100,200]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)

my_dict=df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(np.hstack).to_dict()
```

gives the following dictionary

```
>>> my_dict
{('aa', 'bb'): array([10, 20, 30]), ('aaa', 'bbb'): array([100, 200])}
```

Is there a faster/efficient way of doing this other than using `apply`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension:

```
my_dict= {k:np.hstack(v) for k, v in df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c']}
print (my_dict)
{('aa', 'bb'): array([10, 20, 30]), ('aaa', 'bbb'): array([100, 200])}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `groupby` and `itertuples`:

```
my_dict = dict(df.groupby(['a','b']).agg(list).itertuples(name=None))

{('aa', 'bb'): [10, 20, 30], ('aaa', 'bbb'): [100, 200]}
```

Or more succinctly, as noted by Ch3steR:

```
df.groupby(['a','b']).agg(list).to_dict() 


{('aa', 'bb'): [10, 20, 30], ('aaa', 'bbb'): [100, 200]}
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['a','b']).agg(list).to_dict()` -> `{('aa', 'bb'): [10, 20, 30], ('aaa', 'bbb'): [100, 200]}`

Comment: @Ch3steR much cleaner thanks, added as an answer. I guess indexes get returned as tuples when using `.to_dict` methods.